# Android - Send latitude and longitude to java script from java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show streetview in webview. The following code is working fine.

streetview.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Street View Containers</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #street-view {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      let panorama;

      function initialize() {
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
          document.getElementById("street-view"),
          {
            position: { lat: 37.86926, lng: -122.254811 },
            pov: { heading: 165, pitch: 0 },
            zoom: 1,
          }
        );
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="street-view"></div>

<!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
<script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDSye_pMEK2FplBOupiuAn-grNXQidf6vM&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly"
        async
></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CustomWebView.java

```
webView = new WebView(ctContext);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView
                .addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this),
                        "Android");
if (postData == null) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:/" + "/" + "/android_asset/streetview.html");
        }
```

Now I am trying to send lat and long from the CustomWebView to the java script. Can any one help me on this?

I tried like following:

```
String message = "37.86926,-122.254811";
String function = "initialize('" + message + "')";
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    view.evaluateJavascript(function,null);
                }
            }
        });
```

But not working. Please help me on this.

Comment: Your function call does not end with ;.
Also, please try adding “javascript:” prefix (not 100% sure about that prefix, try with and without).
It should look like ```”javascript:initialize(‘“ + message + ”’);”```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using of `JavascriptInterface` I send data to java script.

Here is the code how I used it..

**CustomWebView.java**

```
webView = new WebView(ctContext);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView
                .addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(37.86926,-122.254811),
                        "JavaScriptInterface"); // Using of this "JavaScriptInterface" we are going to get the value in javascript.
if (postData == null) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:/" + "/" + "/android_asset/streetview.html");
        }
```

**JavaScriptInterface.java**

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    //#endif
    public JavaScriptInterface(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

**streetview.html**

```
function initialize() {
val lati = JavaScriptInterface.getLatitude()
val longi = JavaScriptInterface.getLongitude()
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
          document.getElementById("street-view"),
          {
            position: { lat: lati, lng: longi },
            pov: { heading: 165, pitch: 0 },
            zoom: 1,
          }
        );
      }
```

Using of JavaScriptInterface.getLatitude() and JavaScriptInterface.getLongitude() I can get the value from java to javascript.